# Add OGG Theora Vorbis audio support to IX Web Hoting via htaccess file or markup

Tags: html, .htaccess, hosting, mime-types, html5-audio

I've seen a lot of conflicting information and am not sure how to proceed. I'd like to add OGG MIME type to an htaccess file to support Firefox HTML5 audio/video from my server. I've seen that the file is literally labeled ".htaccess" and that there are a ton of ways of writing the correct MIME type.. What's best? Also, how to install? This is off of an IX Web hosting account.

Here's an example of my HTML5 audio markup.

Thank you!

```
    <audio id="paparazzi">
        <source src="http://www.minimalpluscreative.com/newclients/dev/PAPARAZZI%20(SNL%20MIX).ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        <source src="http://www.minimalpluscreative.com/newclients/dev/PAPARAZZI%20(SNL%20MIX).mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
   </audio>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not sure, [download the `.htaccess`](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess) from [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and use that.  Here's the relevant section (line 77 on):

```
# audio
AddType audio/ogg oga ogg

# video
AddType video/ogg ogv
```

Comment: I think you just changed my life. Why havn't I been developing with boilerplate??